# Implode an inner array values

Tags: php, arrays

An array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Detail] => Array
        (
            [detail_id] => 1
        )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [Detail] => Array
        (
            [detail_id] => 4
        )

    )

)
```

Is it possible to use implode function with above array, because I want to implode `detail_id`  to get `1,4`.

I know it is possible by foreach and appending the array values,
    but want to know whether this is done by implode function or any other inbuilt function in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use some logic - then [array_reduce](http://php.net/array_reduce) is what you need

```
$result = array_reduce($arr, function($a, $b) {
    $result = $b['Detail']['detail_id'];

    if (!is_null($a)) {
        $result = $a . ',' . $result;
    }

    return $result;
});
```

PS: for php <= 5.3 you need to create a separate callback function for that

Comment: If we use long array, whether this will slow down the process.

Comment: @Jusnit: For long array array_reduce() will be a lot faster and memory efficient than rajmohan's solution. This is because, unlike array_map(), it does not need an intermediary array to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

What about something like the following, using `join()`:

```
echo join(',', array_map(function ($i) { return $i['Detail']['detail_id']; }, $array));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this answer.

```
$b = array_map(function($item) { return $item['Detail']['detail_id']; }, $test);

echo implode(",",$b);
```

Comment: Oops, I upvoted your answer by mistake. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @Tadeck. Please check this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array('Detail' => array('detail_id' => 1)),
    array('Detail' => array('detail_id' => 4)),);

$newarray = array();

foreach($array as $items) {
    foreach($items as $details) {
        $newarray[] = $details['detail_id'];
    }
}

echo implode(', ', $newarray);

?>
```